# Как говорить?

Tags: фонетика

Как правильно: грушЕвый или грушОвый?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно говорить "гр***у***ш**е**вый" - проверочное слово "гр***у***ша". Равно как и "сл***и***вовый".

Answer (score -1):

Грушовый: под ударением пишутся суффиксы с гласной о, без ударения с е.

Comment: Да Вы что?! Какой - грушовый? Хоть в гугл загляните!

Comment: Заглянула! ОК!